# How to use Prisma with Electron

Tags: angularjs, typescript, sqlite, electron, prisma

I am using Prisma (sqlite DB) with an Electron + Angular app

Everything works fine until I try to create a record

[I'm getting this error in console few times repeated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0beD.png)

Here is a part of my schema.prisma file:

```
datasource db {
    provider = "sqlite"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
    binaryTargets = ["native","darwin","debian-openssl-1.1.x","linux-musl"]
  }
```

I've tried using the same Prisma config with a scratch TS project and it works fine

When I've tried it with electron I was getting errors

As I understand it cannot find query engine binaries, but I don't know how to say to Electron where to get them from

Comment: *any additional code could be added if necessary

Comment: Are you performing the queries on the frontend? Prisma currently only supports Node at the moment so you would need to write your queries in Electron's main process.

Answer (score 7):

## Hi

I too had similar problem with prisma.

1. The issue is that the custom prisma client along with the downloaded binaries for the platform of use gets generated in `node_modules/.prisma` folder (default).
2. when webpack bundled the code, `.prisma` folder wasn't included with the generated app.asar package in `node_modules` folder and thus prisma client couldn't be loaded along with the binaries.

### Solution

I changed the output path of the generated prisma client as per [prisma doc](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/generating-prisma-client)

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "../src/main/database/generated/client"
}
```

and included in my `database.js` file (located inside `database` folder) as follows

```
import { PrismaClient } from './generated/client';
```

As the downloaded binaries are also placed indside the `output` folder, there was no problem for prisma client in finding it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when using `electron-builder` to build native binaries.
In my case I had to add `.env` file to the build block on `package.json` and change the `output` path as [spc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13123089/spc) mentioned.

```
// package.json
{
 ...
  "build": {
    ...
    "files": [
      ...
      ".env"
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

```
// schema.prisma
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "../electron/client"
  binaryTargets = ["native"]
}
```