# SQL with Prisma under Electron

Tags: sqlite, electron, prisma

My Main goal is to create an Electron App (Windows) that locally stores data in an SQLite Database. And because of type safety I choose to use the [Prisma framework](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-prisma) instead of other SQLite Frameworks.
I took [this Electron Sample Project](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) and now try to include Prisma. Depending on what I try different problems do arrise.

### 1. PrismaClient is unable to be run in the Browser

I executed `npx prisma generate` and then try to execute this function via a button:

```
  import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

  onSqlTestAction(): void {
    const prisma = new PrismaClient();
    const newTestObject = prisma.testTable.create(
      {
        data: {
          value: "TestValue"
        }
      }
    );

  }
```

When executing this in Electron I get this:

```
core.js:6456 ERROR Error: PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser.
In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues
    at new PrismaClient (index-browser.js:93)
    at HomeComponent.onSqlTestAction (home.component.ts:19)
    at HomeComponent_Template_button_click_7_listener (template.html:7)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15281)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15319)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:568)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28666)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
```

It somehow seems logical that Prisma cannot run in a browser. But I actually build a native app - with Electron that embeds a Browser. It seems to be a loophole.

### 2. BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills

So i found this Question: [How to use Prisma with Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64088437/how-to-use-prisma-with-electron)
Seemed to be exactly what I looked for. But the error message is different (Debian binaries were not found).
The solution provided is to generate the prisma artifacts into the `src` folder instead of `node_modules` - and this leads to 19 polyfills errors. One for example:

```
./src/database/generated/index.js:20:11-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '[PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT]\src\database\generated'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

And this repeats with 18 other modules. Since the error message to begin with was different I also doubt that this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out. What I needed to understand was, that all Electron apps consist of 2 parts: The Frontend Webapp (running in embedded Chromium) and a Node backend server. Those 2 parts are called [IPC Main](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) and [IPC Renderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) and they can communicate with each other. And since Prisma can only run on the main process which is the backend I had to send my SQL actions to the Electron backend and execute them there.

### My minimal example

In the frontend (I use Angular)

```
// This refers to the node_modules folder of the Electron Backend, the folder where the main.ts file is located.
// I just use this import so that I can use the prisma generated classes for type safety.

import { TestTable } from '../../../app/node_modules/.prisma/client';

  // Button action
  onSqlTestAction(): void {
    this.electronService.ipcRenderer.invoke("prisma-channel", 'Test input').then((value) => {
      const testObject: TestTable = JSON.parse(value);
      console.log(testObject);
    });
```

The sample project I used already had this service to provide the IPC Renderer:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ElectronService {
  ipcRenderer: typeof ipcRenderer;
  webFrame: typeof webFrame;
  remote: typeof remote;
  childProcess: typeof childProcess;
  fs: typeof fs;

  get isElectron(): boolean {
    return !!(window && window.process && window.process.type);
  }

  constructor() {
    // Conditional imports
    if (this.isElectron) {
      this.ipcRenderer = window.require('electron').ipcRenderer;
      this.webFrame = window.require('electron').webFrame;

      this.childProcess = window.require('child_process');
      this.fs = window.require('fs');

      // If you want to use a NodeJS 3rd party deps in Renderer process (like @electron/remote),
      // it must be declared in dependencies of both package.json (in root and app folders)
      // If you want to use remote object in renderer process, please set enableRemoteModule to true in main.ts
      this.remote = window.require('@electron/remote');
    }
  }
```

And then in the Electron backend I first added `"@prisma/client": "^3.0.1"` to the `package.json` (for the Electron backend not the frontend). Then I added to the `main.ts` this function to handle the requests from the renderer:

```
// main.ts
ipcMain.handle("prisma-channel", async (event, args) => {

  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  await prisma.testTable.create(
    {
      data: {
        value: args
      }
    }
  );

  const readValue = await prisma.testTable.findMany();
  return JSON.stringify(readValue);
})
```

This way of simply adding the IPC Main handler in the `main.ts` file of course is a big code smell but usefull as minimal example. I think I will move on with the achitecture concept presented in [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/electron-ipc-response-request-architecture-with-typescript/).